# A docker reverse proxy that does't rely on the host header?

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, vps

I have a very specific use case for my hobby websites which is that they are made for vintage browsers.

The issue is that some of those browsers don't send the `host` header when sending the request to load the website.

Because of that, my current cpanel hosting solution doesn't work for those browsers because it relies on the `host` header to determine which website is supposed to be loaded.

Now I'm considering moving to a VPS and hosting everything using docker, and I managed to setup my website with `nginx-proxy` with docker which is working perfectly.

The issue is that `nginx-proxy` also relies on the `host` header so those browsers still don't work. I was also looking into `Traefik` but I'm not sure if it supports my use case.

Does anyone know if it's possible to serve multiple websites with docker without having to rely on the `host` header and without having multiple ip addresses?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Forget about Docker for a second. Without the `Host` header, and with a single IP address, how would the proxy / vhost server possibly know which site to serve?

Comment: Exactly, I don't know, I'd like to know if there's another way.

Comment: If there were, then we wouldn't have a Host header.